# How to use Poppins extra bold downloadable font in android

Tags: android, android-fonts

If I check here https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Poppins I can find that it exists in the description.

[image: Example]

But after checking font importer from android studio that type is not there

[image: Android Studio Example]

And I tried to create it using the weight I see a warning in android studio and the font does not seems right:

[image]

---EDIT

Now it shows me this

[image]

Is it possible to use that or there's no other possibility than downloading the font file and have them locally?

Comment: You're right there is this warning. Did you try with latest version 3.6.1 or with the as 4.0 beta 1 or as 4.1 canary 2? And did you test if the font is actually the right one besides the warning?

Comment: In as 3.6.1 the waring is still there and it seems that it is falling back to the font with the weight at 700

Comment: Did you find any solution to this ? I am running into same issue

Answer (score 1):

You could probably download those ttf files from the Google fonts and then put them in assets folder and then u could directly access them using setTypeface dynamically. Use it in Utils class which makes u to reuse across all the Activities. this is the best approach

Comment: But I want to use downloadable fonts, otherwise I will end up using just the maximum bolder font in there.

Comment: You could use the FontRequest and download it and use if if you need so @DanielGomezRico   - refer https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts

Answer (score 0):

You need not to change anything with your poppins_extrabold.xml but what you need to do is use any **Textview** in your layout xml and add

> android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_extrabold"

Comment: Can you show me that "@font/poppins_extrabold" xml? I cant find it

Comment: The thing is that when I apply it in the view the result is the same as bold.xml so it is not loading that font

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps to achieve the same-

1. Add a new folder **assets** in the **app/src/main** directory and add a sub-folder **fonts**
2. Add your **poppins_bold.ttf** file under fonts directory, you just created.
3. Add below lines in your Activity file -

   Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/poppins_bold.ttf");
   yourTextView.setTypeface(font);